# How to build a simple menu-based console application?

Tags: ruby, console-application, user-input

It's been a week since I am learning Ruby. It's an awesome language and I am enjoying it.
I am still a noob. Here's a question:

I want a Console Application in Ruby to ask users to hit Num-Keys to choose options like a program with five functions. First four functions for SUM, SUB, MUL and DIV and last one is for returning to main menu.

I tried to write code but I failed. Here is the code:

```
puts "Choose Option(Press the num key)\n
  1. For SUM\n
  2. For SUB\n
  3. For MUL\n
  4. For DIV\n
  5. For Main Menu"

$x = 22
$y = 32

def gloabl_f(n) # <= global function start here

  def sum(x,y) # <= SUM function
    return x+y
  end

  def sub(x,y) # <= SUB function
    return x-y
  end

  def mul(x,y) # <= MUL function
    return x*y
  end 

  def div(x,y) # <= DIV function
    return x/y
  end

  def Main_Menu()
    return  puts "Choose Option(Press the num key)\n
  1. For SUM\n
  2. For SUB\n
  3. For MUL\n
  4. For DIV\n
  5. For Main Menu"
  end

  n = gets.to_i
  if n == 1
    puts sum(22,32)
  end
end # <= global function end here
```

Basically, I want the user to input two numbers first, and then to be able to choose an option of 1,2,3,4,5 by hitting the numeric keys related to above functions.

Comment: For your information, just because you are using functions doesn't mean you are doing [functional programing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), what you're really is doing is [*procedural programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming).

Comment: oops sorry ok i got this its procedural programming :) Please help me to make this code works

Comment: @Jesper it's not taking the user input and i also don;t know how to call the other functions when user press the number keys(options)

Comment: I also tried global variable but i don't know how to call those global variable into a function's arg.

Comment: It's Jesper, not Jasper. Why do you want to use a global variable?

Comment: Ok let me clear a thing what first i want user to input two number and then choose option 1,2,3,4,5 on hitting the numbers the related function should load #forget_the_global_variable

Comment: I've reformatted your question a little, and added some ignorable whitespaces to code since the inner blocks of text and their indentation made it a little hard to read (at least for me). Also, I've played a little with the question's title, to match the actual problem you have, not the tools you are trying to use. The "tags" section is for that. If I got anything wrong, please don't hesitate to reedit or even completely revert the changes.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Thanks :) I am new here it'll take some times to learn how choose right title and many other things Thanks again :)

Comment: No prob :) One more thing comments are just great, but if you want to **add or explain something**, you should rather **edit** your question and add the details there, just like I did now with your "Ok let me clear a thing what(...)" response. It makes the question clearer and new readers don't need to scan the comments (they can grow really long sometimes..) for every single relevant bit of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some general points

- It isn't very idiomatic to define methods inside of functions
- You're never calling neither `gloabl_f` nor `Main_Menu`, you just define them.

Here's a sample solution:

```
def get_numbers
  puts "First number:"
  x = gets.chomp.to_i
  puts "Second number:"
  y = gets.chomp.to_i
  yield(x,y)
end

def sum(x,y)
  x + y
end

puts "Choose Option:
1. For SUM
2. For SUB
3. For MUL
4. For DIV
5. Exit
"

n = gets.chomp.to_i

case n
  when 1
    get_numbers do |x,y|
      puts "Sum: #{sum(x,y)}"
    end
  when 2
    # code
  when 3
    # code
  when 4
    # code
  else 
    puts "Exiting"
end
```

I left the other options for you to implement.

Comment: Thanks @Jesper for your code and I'll also keep in mind those 2 points. Thanks Again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
puts "Choose Option(Press the num key)\n
1. For SUM\n
2. For SUB\n
3. For MUL\n
4. For DIV\n
5. For Main Menu"
x = 22
y = 32

n = gets.chomp.to_i
if n == 1
    puts x + y
end
```

Comment: @TheLinuxGuy: so, you're not interested in working code?

Comment: na na see the last comment on Jesper's reply i want that #There_is_more_then_one_way_to_do_anything

Comment: you can call main_menu if you put it after global_f. sum, e.t.c Math.sum. methods must named with with small letters

Comment: Again i am new here and it will take some time to learn how to talk on Stack overflow Sorry if it felt rude on my first comment i didn't mean that

Comment: @TheLinuxGuy it seems a bit rash to expect ready-made solutions to the entire problem. You should ask more specific questions.